# How to deactivate window in Qt

Tags: linux, qt, window

I am trying to create a dockable window in Qt (it sits taking 4px width at the edge of the screen, always on top and it slides out when you hover it). I have to use WindowFlag BypassX11WindowManager (in order to hide taskbar hint, disable moving/resizing/etc. from window manager). I use these flags:

```
Qt::FramelessWindowHint
Qt::CustomizeWindowHint
Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint
Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint
```

When I need my dock to be activated, I use the activateWindow() method. However, I have no idea, how to deactivate it.
Is there a way I can force my window deactivate? Now I can do it only by clicking another window and then return to the one that was active before revealing dock.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `->hide()` to simply hide it if you don't want it to appear at certain points.

I assume, by the way, you know there is QDockWidget/ class that may help you as well.  It's unclear from the above if you're using it or not.

Comment: I know the QDockWidget class, but it seems to be something different - just panel that can be unpinned from window. I don't think QDockWidget can exist alone without creating a window at all, am I wrong? To be honest, I've never tried using it. Hiding it is not a way - it has to be visible all the time, just moved to the edge of the screen, so that only the edge of the dock is visible. And I also need this dock to be the main application window, not just a minor little window.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't used a dock widget either!  Your problem didn't really describe that it needs to be "only the edge of the dock is visible".  One thing you could do to make it still be visible, is put the entire set of internal contents in a vbox or similar and then hide the vbox and then resize the window to the size of the "almost empty" vibox.

Comment: I tried QDockWidget and it behaves as any other window if standalone. TaskBar hint ets. is probably hidden on Windows, but on Windows WindowFlag Qt::Tool works well.

Comment: Late for editing:(

I tried QDockWidget and it behaves as any other window if standalone. TaskBar hint ets. is probably hidden on Windows, but on Windows WindowFlag Qt::Tool works well. Unfortunately on Linux it doesn't.
I also tried various combinations of WindowFlags and it seems I can't do it with that.

It's not about what part of window is visible - it's always doable by setting proper coords. All I need is a way to tell the window to deactivate from the app - problem similar to making window that deactivates after clicking the QPushButton in it. If I found it, my problem would be solved.